# inserted form data wont show?

Tags: php, html

I implemented a html form and linked it to an .php file, as shown in a video. It should print the inserted data on the next page, but it gives an HTML ERROR 405.

html:

```
<form action="./connect.php" method="post" id="form">
                        <input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName" placeholder="First Name">
                        <div class="error" id="errorFirstName"></div>
                        
                        <input type="text" id="lastName" name="lastName" placeholder="Last Name">
                        <div class="error" id="errorLastName"></div>
                        
                        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
                        <div class="error" id="errorEmail"></div>
                        
                        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
                        <div class="error" id="errorPassword"></div>

                        <p style="font-size: .9rem; margin-top: 5px; color: #666">Already have an an account? Then <a style="color: royalblue; text-decoration: underline;" href="login.html">login</a>!</p>
                        <button type="submit" id="submit-btn">Sign me Up!</button>
```

php:

```
<?php
print_r($_POST);
?>
```

Comment: [The  placeholder attribute is not a substitute for the label element](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201204/the_html5_placeholder_attribute_is_not_a_substitute_for_the_label_element/)

Answer (score 0):

A [405 error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/405) means the method (POST) is not allowed by your HTTP server.

Unless you've explicitly configured it this way (generally for security reasons), it usually means the server is tuned for serving static files and does not have any server-side programming capabilities.

This is commonly seen when people are trying to deploy to GitHub Pages or test using the Visual Studio Code Live Server.

To run your PHP you will need to use an HTTP server that supports PHP.

Comment: I'm testing my website with the VSC Live Server. How can I use an HTTP Server that supports the php file? If I open the file with the explorer, the .php file code shows on the page and this is obviously not the outcome I want.

Comment: Opening the file with explorer means that you are replacing "Live Server" (which doesn't support PHP) with "no server" (which can't support PHP). [Pick a server](https://duckduckgo.com/?va=j&t=hc&q=best+local+development+server+for+php&ia=web). Download it. Install it. Follow the instructions for it.